# Track entry & exit pages with PHP session

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I currently have the following code (which works from what I can tell so far)

```
session_start();

if(!is_array($_SESSION['page'])) {
 $_SESSION['page']=array();
}

$_SESSION['page'][]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$entry=reset($_SESSION['page']);

$exit=end($_SESSION['page']);
```

Is this the best way to accomplish tracking of entry and exit pages with PHP?

Edit:

This (from @T0xicCode) appears to be a better option:

```
session_start();

if(!is_array($_SESSION['page'])) {
  $_SESSION['page'] = array('entry' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

$_SESSION['page']['exit'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$entry = $_SESSION['page']['entry'];

$exit = $_SESSION['page']['exit'];
```

Comment: what is exit page? What if I opened several pages and then close them together? What if I opened 1MMMMM pages? Do you have enough memory to store it?

Comment: For my purposes, the exit page is the last page on which the user clicks an outbound link that triggers the script that stores the entry/exit variables. So, opening several pages/tabs should be fine, as this data will be stored appropriately for each outgoing click that triggers the script. Then entry page shouldn't change, but the exit page would for each (if any) additional click(s).

Comment: Ahh...didn't think about memory issues. Is that a reasonable concern?

Comment: memory limit by default 128mb, standard url is about 100 bytes, so you will have problems when user/google bot will visit about 1M pages during 1 session, for small sites it is not a problem, but for huge forums/shops...

Comment: Assuming I have the default session lifetime of 24 minutes - wouldn't this take care of the memory issues? Or not, since the session is automatically stored in a cookie? I'm confused about how that works...

Comment: session cookie lifetime will not help you, this value is used to determine how long session will be alive after "last page hit", if person/bot continue request pages - this time means nothing

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like google analytics, but if you want a DIY, pure php solution, something like the following should work. It doesn't track the pages in the middle, which your original solution does.

```
session_start();

if(!in_array('page', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['page'])) {
  $_SESSION['page'] = array('entry' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

$_SESSION['page']['exit'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$entry = $_SESSION['page']['entry'];

$exit = $_SESSION['page']['exit'];
```

You'll also have to determine how often you'll purge old sessions. If I come back after 2 weeks, is it a new browsing session, or is it the continuation of the old one?

Comment: just note: this will not track actual exit page, but last opened page, which is not very big difference usually, to track really last page you should go with javascript-based solutions, it will give you better understanding what page was closed last

Comment: Wouldn't the exit page be the last page visited anyway?

Comment: no, I can open: "page1", "page2", then close "page2", then close "page1", with php solution exit page will be page2, with js - page1

Comment: I see, in that case, I'd agree with you on the javascript tracker.

Comment: I should have mentioned, it needs to be in-house and server side only. So JS and GA are not an option for me.

Comment: T0xicCode : Yes, I don't need any of the pages in the middle, just entry/exit - so thanks for the code. Regarding session purging, I thought sessions auto-purge after 24 minutes unless the server is instructed otherwise?

Comment: @user3650556 session is purged after 24 minutes from last page hit

Comment: @T0xicCode after testing your code more thoroughly, I realized that the entry page isn't stored. The solution I originally posted above still works, but I like how your solution doesn't store any pages other than the entry and exit to the array (no need to waste memory if I don't need the info). I'm confused about what the IF statement in your code does...

Comment: @user3650556 It checks if the session variable does not contains an entry named 'page' or (the session variable contains an entry named 'page' and the entry is not an array) and only run the code in the parentheses if either condition is true. This ensures that the entry page is only stored once. The problem is that your old code already defined the page entry, so you should clear the sessions (or clear your cookies) for the code to work properly.

Comment: So it looks like the first part of the OR in the IF is causing problems for me. If I omit the !in_array('page', $_SESSION) then it works as it should. Otherwise, $entry is the same as $exit. The complete block of code that's working for me is now included in my original question.